# How could I make a dynamic banner change background color with JS based on a image?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, dynamic, banner

I'm making some dynamic banners and I wanted to reduce the number of variants with eliminating the color variations. I was thinking about changing the background color and text color based on what logo that gets fetched from the feed. There are only two logo variations. Therefore I thought an If/else statement would do the trick. But I can't get it to work. I need it to change the color of the body based on if "NoBorder.png" is the src image of "i19" or not. I need an explanation for a solution since I'm pretty new to JS. `

```
<body onload="choseBG();" id="banner">    

<script>
       var logoImg = document.getElementById("i19").src;
        function choseBG(){    

            if(logoImg = 'assets/NoBorder.png'){
                document.getElementById('banner').style.backgroundColor = '#CCCCCC'
            }else{
                document.getElementById('banner').style.backgroundColor = '#f20403'
            }}
    </script>`
```

Comment: What is the value of 'console.log(bgImg);' also  checking is not correct please replace as `if(bgImg ===  'assets/NoBorder.png')`

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/felp/how-to-ask)

Comment: What is an "ELI5" and what does it have to do with your question?

Comment: An eli5 is "Explain Like I'm five" :) Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: What is the question here? What is not working? Where is `bgImg` coming from? Why are you setting it to a value it your `if` condition? Please read [ask].

Comment: Hi, sorry. Tried to edit the description now :) Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Please check the code below

```js
var bgImg = 'assets/NoBorder.png';
function choseBG(){    
 console.log(bgImg);
 if(bgImg === 'assets/NoBorder.png'){
  document.getElementById('banner').style.backgroundColor = '#cccccc'
 }else{
  document.getElementById('banner').style.backgroundColor = '#f20403'
 }
}
```

```html
<body onload="choseBG();" id="banner">

</body>
```

Comment: What have you changed? And why?

Answer (score 1):

`bgImg = 'assets/NoBorder.png'` is an assignment and doesn't work as test in an `if()`.

As working test you need `bgImg === 'assets/NoBorder.png'`

Comment: So what would you have used instead?

Comment: see answer of Ajith better use ```===```.